# Alpine Linux - restrict su -l to wheel group

Tags: su, alpine-linux

What's the best way to restrict `su -l` only to people who are in a specific group? I'm on Alpine Linux. I've already added `linux-pam` package but I'm not able to make it run.

That's my current `/etc/pam.d/su`

```
# basic PAM configuration for Alpine.
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
auth            include         base-auth
account         include         base-account
password        include         base-password
session         include         base-session-noninteractive
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that `pam_wheel` module was installed.

All necessary info (with examples) you can get from [man 8 pam_wheel](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_wheel).

Some example which can be used `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
auth            required        pam_wheel.so trust group=wheel
auth            substack        system-auth
```